# Looking for correct Laravel route | getting photos from database

Tags: html, laravel

Maybe there's somebody, who could help me with this Laravel problem – I am working on a very very simple portfolio project, where I want to get some photos from a database and post them in simple flexbox layout. For now, the code is following:

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $venice_photos = \App\VenicePhoto::orderBy('id', 'ASC')
    ->take(6)
    ->get();

    return view('pages.venice', [
        'venice_photos' => $venice_photos,
    ]);
});
```

Blade file :

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($venice_photos as $venicePhoto)
        <div class="block block-photo" style="background: url({{$venicePhoto->img}}) no-repeat 50% 50%; background-size: cover;"></div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Each `div` should post 6 photos from a database and there should be at least 4 `div`s . But photos should not repeat. I tried the next `div` with `@if ($venicePhoto->id > 6)`, but it didn't work out. So the question is - where and how do I state the rule, that photos in each `div` should have unique id?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the photo collection with the `chunk` method.

The `chunk` method breaks the collection into multiple, smaller collections of a given size:

```
$collection = collect([$photo1, $photo12, $photo13, $photo14, $photo15, $photo16, $photo17]);

$chunks = $collection->chunk(4);

$chunks->toArray();

// [[$photo11, $photo12, $photo13, $photo14], [$photo15, $photo16, $photo17]]
```

Then you'll have to make two foreach so that there are at least 4 divs with photos, and as many div groups as there are photos.

**Unique photos**

If you want the photos not to be repeated you have to verify that they will all be different

The `unique` method returns all of the unique items in the collection. The returned collection keeps the original array keys, so in this example we'll use the values method to reset the keys to consecutively numbered indexes:

```
$collection = collect([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]);

$unique = $collection->unique();

$unique->values()->all();

// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm checking both methods, but they seem to be way beyond my Laravel knowledge. Shoukd the Route look smth like this?  `Route::get('/', function () {

$collection = collect([7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]);
$unique = $collection->unique();
$unique->values()->all();

$venice_photos = \App\VenicePhoto::orderBy('id', 'ASC')
->take(6)
->get();

return view('pages.venice', [
'venice_photos' => $venice_photos,
]);
   
});`

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved this with "skip":

```
$venice_photos_2 = \App\VenicePhoto::orderBy('id', 'ASC')
->skip(6)
->take(6)
->get();
```

So in each section I skipped previous photos and posted next 6 photos from database. This would not work, if amount of data/photos would be larger though.